# What's the difference between "voll" and "völligen"?

Tags: difference

is there a difference between voll and völligen? 
when do i use each of them?
Thanks in advance

Comment: These are entirely different words: **voll** and **völlig**. Please look them up in the dictionary and don't let you confuse by the *full* and *fully* meanings of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "völligen" in a sentence, the next wort that follows is a noun. Using an article after "völligen" is wrong.

Du erzählst voll den Schwachsinn.

Du erzählst völligen Schwachsinn.

Comment: Sehr umgangssprachlich...